# Sequence Id is not generating for list of object from restcontroller in springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to save the list of approver details that I got from the request, but it is giving an error message mentioned below. If I pass a single approver object instead of a list, then it is saving the data. Please help to store the list of approver entities.

```
    @Entity
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Table(name="Approver_DETAILS")
    public class Approver implements Serializable{
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="seq",sequenceName="approver_seq",allocationSize=1)
    @Column(name="app_pk)
    private int id
    
    @Column(name="app_pk)
    private String subLOB
    
    }
    
    @RestController
    public class appCController{
    
    @Autowired
    Repo repo;
    
    @PostMapping(value="/upload")
    public ResponseEntity<String> upload(@RequestBody List<Approver> approver){
    
        repo.saveAll(approver);
return new ResponseEntity<>("success",HttpStatus.OK);

    }
    
    }
    
    Request:
    
    [
    {
    "subLOB":"xxx"
    },
    {
    "subLOB":"yyy"
    }
    ]
    
    Error Response:
    
    Invalid property "id" of bean class [com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap]: Could not find field for property during fallback
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#batch-session-batch).

Hibernate does not perform insert the identity identifier generator.

Comment: I didn't get your point.  I am using spring boot data JPA